# TXT-File - Split different content with c#

Tags: c#, split, streamreader

i have little problem with importing a txt-file into the database.
The structure of the file is a little bit difficult.
At the first rows are only descriptions like:

- Typ    Dummy
- Status Ready
- Number 3
  and so on.

After the descriptions (between 20 and 22 rows) comes a table like:

```
PartStatus    Result  Measurement1      Measurement2      .....
900           OK      0                 20                .....
600           Passed  30                400               .....
```

I don't know, at which row the table start. 
What's the best way, to read and handle the file to write it into a database?

At the moment i work with the StreamReader and add each string into a datatable.

Regards

Armin

SampleFile:
[TestFile](http://pastebin.com/DMiV3b1r)

Comment: Could you give us a sample of the CSV?

Comment: Having a sample file to look at will make it easier to answer. Can you share one?

Comment: Whats the best way to upload the file?

Comment: @NimraF http://pastebin.com/ maybe? Don't make people download it, just link it.

Comment: @NimraF Looking at that file, it seems to me that only part of it is valid as a delimited file (with tabs) I'm not entirely sure if any of the libraries mentioned will work unless the file is modified. Technically the file is not a CSV (I think)

Comment: @Adam - Sorry, your right. Its an txtfile.

Comment: right, but the problem comes in that its not formatted like a csv (or even a tab delimited file). No I can see why you tagged it with split. Does the file have a changing number of items at the top?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [File Helpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/). I have dabbled with it in the past, that may simplify the process of reading the CSV.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TextFiledParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128079) class and just skip invalid lines.

```
using (var reader = new TextFieldParser(@"c:\YourFile"))
{
    reader.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    reader.Delimiters = new string[] {","};
    string[] currentRow = null;
    while (!reader.EndOfData)
    {
        try
        {
            currentRow = reader.ReadFields();
            // do something with the values
        }
        catch (MalformedLineException ex)
        {
            // skip invalid lines and handle it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also dedicated CSV parsing support in the [CommonLibrary.NET](http://commonlibrarynet.codeplex.com/) project on Codeplex. You can find an example of CSV parsing with this library [here](http://commonlibrarynet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home&ANCHOR#Csv).

**UPDATE**

Here is some code that can be used for parsing a text similar to the one you have above, and using *CommonLibrary.NET*. Note that the original text is first cut down to start at the table header (`origText.Substring(origText.IndexOf("PartStatus"))`), and regular expression matching is used to replace one or more consecutive space characters with a single comma (`Regex.Replace(sometext, "[ ]+", ",")`):

```
var origText =
    "Type Dummy\n" +
    "Status Ready\n" +
    "# Comment line\n" +
    "# Another comment line\n" +
    "PartStatus    Result  Measurement1      Measurement2\n" +
    "900           OK      0                 20\n" +
    "600           Passed  30                400\n";

var trimmedText = 
    Regex.Replace(origText.Substring(origText.IndexOf("PartStatus")), 
                  "[ ]+", ",");

var csvDoc = Csv.LoadText(trimmedText, true, false, ",");

Console.WriteLine(csvDoc.Get<int>(1, "Measurement2"));
Console.WriteLine(csvDoc.Get<string>(0, "Result"));
```

will yield the output:

```
400
OK
```

The CSV parsing component of *CommonLibrary.NET* also provides a simple way to transform your CSV data into an *ADO.NET* `DataTable`:

```
var table = csvDoc.ToDataTable();
```